# Why isn't pandas df.plot.bar() accepting an array for width?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html), matplotlib's `bar` and `barh` accept a single value or an array of widths, one for each bar. I've seen examples of this around. However, it's not working when using the pandas wrapper, and the stack trace suggests that the arithmetic which checks for the x-limits (y-limits, respectively, for `barh`) can't handle multiple widths. What's going on?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Minimum reproducible bug
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [3,5,4], 'width': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0]})
plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
df.plot.barh(ax=ax[0], width=0.9, stacked=True)  # Base case
df.plot.bar(ax=ax[1], width=df.width.values)     # Throws error after drawing bars, before setting x-limits
df.plot.barh(ax=ax[2], width=df.width.values)    # (Analogous to above)
```

Comment: Is your question, why pandas plot can't handle width arrays or how to create a graph from pandas with multiple widths? Please note also, that `width` always refers to the length along the x-axis, giving it a different meaning in `bar` and `barh`.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. pyplot.bar can handle multiple widths without problem as the linked documentation suggests. The problem you face here comes from `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, which does not wrap matplotlib well in this case. Indeed, the question is also not clear on what it's looking for: an explanation why this does not work, or a workaround?

Comment: Whoops, yes I am looking for a workaround, and my intent when I say 'width' is the width of the bar, its dimension that's parallel to the index axis.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the obvious workaround is to use matplotlib directly, because it handles multiple widths/heights as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [3,5,4], 'width': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax[0].barh(df.index, df.value, height=df.width)
ax[1].bar(df.index, df.value, width=df.width)
ax[2].barh(df.index, df.value, height=df.width)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done this, but because my real use case is a stacked bar, I have to write a for loop that starts to feel like re-inventing the pandas wrapper.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the way to go.